# yum cannot update or create new users/roles yii

Tags: yii-extensions, user-permissions, user-management, user-roles

I have installed YUM in yii. But when i click on create new user it display  page like this [image: Create User]

The same when i click on Grand permission 
[image: Grand permission picture]
and on roles displays
[image]
Any help will be appreciated.